# $User.UITheme not working on viualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, ui

I'm trying to detect on a visualforce page that is the page opened in a classic or Lightning view in Salesforce. For this I'm using "$User.UITheme" and "$User.UIThemeDisplayed" on the visualforce page and it is always return "Theme3".
Also, when I use the UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed() method in the controller and display on the page it shows "Theme3" instead of "Theme4d" even if I'm in the lightning experience.

Here is the controller code:-

```
public with sharing class CheckUITheme {

    public String themeViewed{get;set;}

    public CheckUITheme(){
        themeViewed = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
        System.debug('>>>>>'+UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed());
    }
}
```

Here is the Visualforce page code:-

```
 <apex:page controller="CheckUITheme"> 
  <h1>Congratulations</h1> This is your new Page
>>>>>>>>{!themeDisplayed}>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>{!themeViewed}>>>>>>>>> {!$User.UITheme} {!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}  
</apex:page>
```

and the output which I get is :-

Congratulations This is your new Page >>>>>>>Theme3>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>Theme3>>>>>>>>> Theme3 Theme3

What wrong m I doing here or is there a bug in the Salesforce method?

Comment: Tried changing versions of apex class and page?

Comment: @RahulSharma, which version of apex class and visualforce page should I use?

Comment: try upgrading or downgrading to different versions maybe in between `37.0` to `42.0`

Comment: @RahulSharma, I tried changing the version from 28-42 but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"{!$User.UITheme} {!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}", worked for me on the visualforce page when I used it in a inline visualforce page with the Standard controller and when I previwed the page as a visualforce page only it does not work.
Strange but, the theme detection works for standard controllers on a inline VF page.

Comment: This appears to behave inconsistently in our org. Some pages I can use a customController and Theme4 is returned for Lightning. Other times I not only have to use a standard controller and extension, but have to override the 'View' button/action to get my vf page to display something other than Theme3 in Lightning.